# Hosting multiple applications on one server

Tags: infrastructure

I have several applications using Laravel PHP. Each application is hosted on 2 separate VPS: application and database. For applications that require Redis, it will be run on another separate server.

Applications are hosted on machines with 8 CPU cores and 8 GB of RAM, but the load on them is small: CPU LA ~0.35 - 1.7 and 40-80% of unused memory.

This is done so that if one application freezes, it does not interfere with other applications. However, this is expensive and there are many unused resources.

The question arises: is it possible to place applications on the same server so that they do not interfere with each other?